# how to consistently do subscribe Observable? (RxJS)

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, subscribe

I ran into a problem:
I need to get the data of comments (for users) first, secondly get data of users and correlate comments and users:

Structure data:

```
comment:
id,
date,
userId,
message

--------

user:
id,
name
```

I want to get comments and add user-name for every getting comment.
I.e. I want to have comment contain user-name:

```
comment:
id,
date,
userId,
message,
userName
```

I read the documentation for rxjs, but because of the abundance of various operators I do not know what suits me.

I try it

```
//get comments
return this.getMovieComments(movieId).pipe(
      //form array ids users by comments
      mergeMap(comments => {
        const ids = comments.map(c => c.userId);
        //get users
        return this.userService.searchUsers({ id: ids });
      })
    ).subscribe((users) => { console.log(users) });
```

It is works, but I just get list users, I do not know how me correlate data from **getMovieComments()** and from **searchUsers()** then get desired result.

Sorry if that obvious things. I am beginner of RxJS

Comment: Side question, but: why use reduce instead of map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way could be the following

```
return this.getMovieComments(movieId).pipe(
  concatMap(comments => {
     const ids = comments.map(comment => comment.id);
     return this.userService.searchUsers({ id: ids }).pipe(
        // via this map operation we return both the comments and the users to the next operator in the pipe
        map(users => ({users, comments})
     )
  }),
  map(({users, comments}) => {
     // here users and comments are 2 arrays and so it is possible to assign the user name to the comment - the exact logic may depend on how the arrays are sorted
  })
)
```

Answer (score 0):

In this line

```
return this.userService.searchUsers({ id: ids });
```

you can combine it with `comments` (which you already have):

```
return forkJoin(of(comments), this.userService.searchUsers({ id: ids }));
```